# about arrays and a logical error

Tags: c++, arrays

I expect the code below to print the numbers in ascending order or descending but when I give `cout` statement all I get is the same array back. I am not able to make out where I am making mistake (and I am using this method because this program is needed for school and I don't want any function to do this for me)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>   //<utility> for C++11
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int array[5] = { 1,4,6,9,5 };
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
        {
            if (array[i]<array[j])
            {
                swap(array[i], array[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    for (int k = 0; k<5; k++)
        cout << array[k] << "    ";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do proper initialization: `int i = 0; `.

Comment: I think it's important that we see the swap() function.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  sorry that was a typo

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: I suspect that `swap` is being called by value. Can't wait to find out.

Comment: `int j=0+1` is intentional?

Comment: It looks like it works [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/41755c1af6c29ef5)

Comment: and here too http://ideone.com/aC5ObH :)

Comment: It's not uncommon for bugs caused by typos to magically disappear when you retype code. Use copy and paste.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code. It works as you want. It sorts the array.

Comment: Yes! it worked i also copied and pasted. i don't know why didn't it work earlier for me, i am really really SORRY for wasting your time.
should i delete my question?

Answer (score 1):

I think the 4th line should be:

```
for (int j = i + 1; j < 5; j++)
```

Also the swap function will need to pass by reference:

```
void swap(int &a, int &b)
{
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = a;
}
```

Comment: FYI, they are using `std::swap`.